# Loader div is not hiding onload function for dynamic generated iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am using this code to generate and download PDF file.
Here is the sample code,

```
<div id="ajax_loading"></div>

function print_profile(pid,vid)
{
    $("#ajax_loading").show();
    var type=$("input[name=share_to]:checked").val();
    var perpage=$("input[name=perpage]:checked").val();

    var url=storeurl+"/ajax/ajax-action.php?type="+type+"&vid="+vid+"&playlist_id="+pid+"&perpage="+perpage+"&action=get_profile";
    var iframe = document.getElementById("download-container");
    iframe.src = url;
}
```

And i have iframe in footer like this,

```
<iframe id="download-container" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px;" onload="document.getElementById('ajax_loading').style.display='none';"></iframe>
```

Here, when `print_profile` function will call, it create dynamic URL and set it in iframe. So iframe loads that url and download that file. What i am trying to do is, When iframe generating PDF, need to show loading div. so for that i added this function in iframe,

```
onload="document.getElementById('ajax_loading').style.display='none';"
```

But its not working for me. id there any solution for this? Am i doing anything wrong here?

Here is jsfiddle which is working for content URL [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a48acxk/2/) but its not working with my URL. i think it because my URL is generating output?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Is the loading div not displaying?

Comment: @phpcoderx actually it not hiding after file generation

Comment: @phpcoderx if i replace my `url` with any other like google or stackoverflow.com then it will works. but when i set url which generating output file, its not working

Comment: Did you try checking the console for errors?

Comment: yes, no error in console